# Tutorials or screencasts on building a REST web service on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services

I am looking to build a **REST webservice** on Rails to serve as the **server side component to my mobile app**. Can someone point out some *tutorials* or *screencasts* on building REST webservices for someone who is learning Rails?

The main features I am looking for are:

1. Authorization(user id and password validation).
2. Posting data from the client (mobile app) to the server database using REST API

I am also okay if you could point me to some book where content on creating a rest api is available.

It would also be great if someone could post a bit of code to get me started on this.

I am relatively new to Rails and have almost finished the book "Ruby on Rails Tutorials" by Michael Hartl. This is my only experience with Rails, so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I wrote 2 blog posts that you'll probably find helpful:

http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/04/10/implementing-a-public-api-in-rails-3/

http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/04/17/consuming-a-public-rails-api-with-jquery/

They're not tutorials, but it should get you going.

The basic idea is: expose JSON data through controller actions when a request is made with the `.json` format.

Cross domain requests (like the ones you'll be doing from your mobile app) are a little trickier, as explained in the blog post: you'll actually need to send javascript within a callback, or your code won't work (you'll get an empty response). (Explained in the first post.)

Once the data is exposed as JSON, simply query it from your mobile app (as explained in the 2nd post).

EDIT: Manning has a book on Rails 3 (one of the authors being none other than Yehuda Katz) with a chapter on creating an API: http://manning.com/katz/ In particular, it covers token authorization for the API using Devise.

Comment: Thanks david.This makes sense now.I am a newbie to rails and moving along.I wanted to return response in text format which i found can be done by render :text=>'string'.Btw good posts.

Comment: See updated comment: the referenced book might be of interest to you in learning how to implement a Rails API.

Comment: @Taruni, you're welcome! They're written to help people out ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you visit [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/). If you search on various keywords you'll get a wealth of information. I used 'REST', 'routes', 'controller' to get myself started...

Comment: Tried it.But could not get a whole lot of information on building rest api's.It looks great otherwise

Comment: Try this one in particular: http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem?view=asciicast