# Web Service and Endpoints in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and I am creating a RoR web application, their is a mobile component that will connect (CRUD) to the default db I am creating. I need some guidance in writing the web service component and what valid endpoints should look like in this type of app. Any direction would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails provides restful web service development out of the box, i.e. any app developed on RoR is by nature a RESTful web service.  To answer the specifics of your question, consider checking out this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099305/tutorials-or-screencasts-on-building-a-rest-web-service-on-rails)