# How do you get data from a server via Ruby and then pass this data into Java/Android classes?

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am making a simple todo list Android application using Ruby (Specifically ActiveRecord) to get data from a database containing Users (made up of attributes like name, emails, todo lists etc). My problem is I want to pass the User data from the Ruby to the Java/Android code (for example to load all a users information after login). 
Similarly, how would I pass data from the Java/Android code back to ruby, so that it may update a users information on the database when necessary?

Please keep in mind that I MUST use ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to get data by hitting URL on web from your mobile Android app:

You need to just create web services in Ruby that will return you data in the different formats like `JSON, HTML, YAML, XML` from which you can parse it on your mobile app. Usually we prefer JSON/XML formats data that will be easy to parse on mobile site.

Here you go, for creating RESTful api in Rails there are many tutorials and example are available on web like below:

[Tutorials or screencasts on building a REST web service on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099305/tutorials-or-screencasts-on-building-a-rest-web-service-on-rails)

http://pivotallabs.com/building-a-fast-lightweight-rest-service-with-rails-3/

http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning

http://gavinmorrice.com/blog/posts/21-building-a-rest-api-in-rails-3

http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/sample-rest-api-example-in-rails/

http://jes.al/2013/10/architecting-restful-rails-4-api/

Answer (score 1):

Ruby will go as far as serving the data to your android application. In order for your android application to be able to 'understand' the data it receives, both the server and your android application need to agree on an **exchange format**, in which the data is to be encoded: `json`, `xml`, `yaml`, or even a more sophisticated **serialization framework** like `protobuf`, if there is a compelling need to go there.

You might want to start by looking up those.